# PricebookEntry List not populated in query, don't understand why

Tags: apex, soql, pricebook

I have the following code block:

```
 Map<Id, Product2> productMap = new Map<Id, Product2>();
              List<Product2> prodList = new List<Product2>();
              Set<String> productIds = new Set<String>();
              Set<String> setCurrency = new Set<String>();

              for(WS_OpportunityUpdate.ProductLine p:org.ProductLines){
                    productIds.add(p.strSAPProductCode);
                    setCurrency.add(p.strCurrency);
                    system.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO,'Productids is: '+productIds);
                    system.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO,'setCurrency is: '+setCurrency);
                }
                // Get all Products that are being referenced in the Product Lines

               prodList = [SELECT Id,Name,txtSAPProductCode__c from Product2 where txtSAPProductCode__c in:ProductIds];

               for(Product2 pe:prodList){
               productMap.put(pe.Id,pe);
               system.debug('Id: '+pe.Id);
               system.debug('Name: '+pe.Name);
               system.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO,'productMap: '+productMap);
               }


              // First, the Custom Pricebook
              Pricebook2 priceb = [SELECT Id from Pricebook2 where Name = 'Custom Global Pricebook' LIMIT 1];
              system.debug('Pricebook Id: '+priceb.Id);


              // Get list of PricebookEntries
              List<PricebookEntry> pbEntryList = new List<PricebookEntry>();



              pbEntryList = [Select Id, Product2Id, Pricebook2Id from PricebookEntry where Pricebook2Id =:priceb.Id AND Product2Id in:productIds];
```

the above code takes input from a SOAP based webservice and puts those into the variables to be used for SOQL.  The problem is that the last query

```
pbEntryList = [Select Id, Product2Id, Pricebook2Id from PricebookEntry where Pricebook2Id =:priceb.Id AND Product2Id in:productIds];
```

always returns empty and i can't see why.  I've tried to set the values in the Set by hand and also tested if the Custom GLobal Pricebook query returns a value through anonymous apex (it does).

Can you see what I'm missing here?

Comment: Are you using the same user to execute Anonymous Apex and SOAP call?

Comment: yes.  The same user.

Comment: Can you try to debug the values of priceb.Id AND productIds ?

Comment: I've done that too.  They check out just fine.  I'm probably just missing some small detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared a set of string

```
Set<String> productIds = new Set<String>();
```

into which you are populating non salesforce ids  (believe its SAP product codes)

```
productIds.add(p.strSAPProductCode);
```

and using that to get the matching salesforce products

```
prodList = [SELECT Id,Name,txtSAPProductCode__c from Product2 where txtSAPProductCode__c in:ProductIds];
```

but when you are querying pricebook entries, you are using the same external sap product codes instead of the salesforce product ids

```
pbEntryList = [Select Id, Product2Id, Pricebook2Id from PricebookEntry 
      where Pricebook2Id =:priceb.Id AND Product2Id in:productIds];
```

the productids set is not having salesforce ids.. so this won't work, instead you should use the retrieved salesforce product ids

```
pbEntryList = [Select Id, Product2Id, Pricebook2Id from PricebookEntry 
      where Pricebook2Id =:priceb.Id AND Product2Id in : prodList];
```

Comment: Thanks for that clarification.  Exactly was I was missing.  I learn something new everyday, like the fact that I could use a List from a SOQL query as a set to match Id's from.  I didn't know you could do that :)